# How to define a script in the venv/bin dir with pyproject.toml (in hatch or any other wrapper)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, hatch

Im unsure about the [new doc](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-pyproject-toml) on packaging with [hatch](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/) and wonder if someone worked out how to define a script in a pip installable package. So in short I need to be able to direct `python -m build` to make a package with `open_foo_bar.py` as in the example, install into the `(virtual env)/bin` dir.

my package looks like this (after a python -m build step that generated dist dir)

```
pypi_package/
├── bin
│   └── open_foo_bar.py
├── dist
│   ├── foo-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
│   └── foo-0.1.0.tar.gz
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── test_pkg
    ├── foolib.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Im trying to get `bin/open_foo_bar.py` installed into the `$(virtual env)/bin` instead it installs it into the `site-packages/bin`

```
./lib/python3.10/site-packages/bin/open_foo_bar.py
```

myproject.toml is

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"


[project]
name = "FOO"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [
  { name="Mr Foo", email="foo@bar.com" },
]
description = "a Foo bar without drinks"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.8"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

dependencies = [
  'requests'
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "http://footopia.s/howto_foo"
```

This used to be easy by defining the `scripts` section in setup.py

```
setuptools.setup(
   ...
   scripts ['bin/script1'],
   ... 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [theory](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/#using-package-metadata) the Python spec defines how entrypoints and scripts are supposed to be handled.

`Hatch` has chosen to do it a bit differently, and I'm not sure if this is even considered best-practice. This approach combines [Forced Inclusion](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#forced-inclusion) with [Metadata Entrypoints/CLI](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/metadata/#cli).

Here's how you might achieve your desired outcome:

1. Add a `main` or `run` function to your script `open_foo_bar.py`
2. Force `hatch` to make your script appear as part of the package once it is installed. You would add the lines:

```
[tool.hatch.build.targets.sdist.force-include]
"bin/open_foo_bar.py" = "test_pkg/open_foo_bar.py"

[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel.force-include]
"bin/open_foo_bar.py" = "test_pkg/open_foo_bar.py"
```

3. Create an entrypoint using the scripts section:

```
[project.scripts]
open_foo_bar = "test_pkg.open_foo_bar:main"
```

When you install the package, `open_foo_bar` should be in your virtualenv `bin/` directory, and it will call your `main` function within `open_foo_bar.py`, which will have been moved to reside within your package in `site-packages`.

It's a hacky solution, but there doesn't appear to be a 1:1 feature for supporting arbitrary scripts. `Hatch` actually does mention the usage of an [Entrypoints](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/metadata/#plugins) section, but it's catered towards plugin management.

Comment: Nice!..  Going to have to play more with this to fully grasp that concept. But it does make a script in bin.  thanks!

Comment: `pip install -e .`  (live dev mode) also seems to work with this method.